# How can I extend home wifi range to separate metal shop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have an AT&T wireless network that works great for my home. I also have a workshop about 50 yards from my home, made of tin siding. I'd like to be able to access the wireless network while working inside the shop. What would be the best way to extend the network from my home, so that the signal is strong inside the shop? I've looked into wifi range extenders, but it seems like the metal siding of the shop is going to block most signals. Any ideas?

Comment: Most extenders support being placed into an AP configuration.  This means you provide it a connection to your network through a LAN cable, allow you to have multiple access points to the same network.  This of course would require you route a lan cable outside, but you wanted to know, how you could extend your range and that is how you would do it.

Comment: Run 2 wires - one for ethernet, one for phone line.  Add an access point in the shop.  Or just a switch and more network cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metal siding will most likely be a large problem.  The most reliable solution would be to get an access point and mount this in the shed. You would then want to run a cable, preferable outdoor rated Ethernet, to the AP in the shed. The theoretical max length is 300 feet.

A range extender even in the most optimal settings will still cut your bandwidth in half. Wiring an AP to your network will increase your WiFi range without this issue.